# Seeding package tables in Laravel 4

Tags: php, model-view-controller, laravel, laravel-4

I am aware of how to set up Package Migrations on Laravel 4 (using --bench="vendor/package" / --package="vendor/package").

But I can't seem to work out how to set up seeds for those migrations?

-- To clarify - I am aware of how to use the seeder, what I need to know is how to setup up a seed file for a standalone package? You can give a package separate migrations...

Comment: Your question is a little vague - but why cant you just use db:seed?

Comment: I have updated it to make it a little more clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the Seeder class like in app folder.

[Database Seeding in Laravel 4](http://four.laravel.com/docs/migrations)

For exemple :

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Page;

class MySeeder extends Seeder {

    public function run()
    {
        Page::create(array('title' => 'Foo-Bar !'));
    }

}
```

and specify " --class " arg in :

```
$ php artisan db:seed --class="MySeeder"
```

Take care to make your class loaded by composer :)

Comment: Excellent thanks @pierrepierre-broucz.

Would I need to call:

    $ php artisan db:seed --class="Vendor\Package\MySeeder"

Comment: Assuming "MySeeder" class is correctly loaded by composer, you just need to call the seeder : `--class="MySeeder"`, not the complete path.

Comment: This work fine for you ? if you update the question with your folder structure i can help you for composer.json params

Comment: You also have to add the folder containing your MySeeder class to the composer classmap. Add "src/database" for example to your package composer.json file and then run composer dump-autoload

Answer (score 3):

**Laravel Database Seeder** automagically recognizes any class name passed to it, as long as **Composer** has loaded all your classes successfully. Do as follows:

1. Create a `seeds` folder under `{vendor}/{package}/src`
2. Create a seeder class, prefix it with your package name to avoid
   conflicts, for instance, `{Package}Seeder.php` would work.
3. Add the new `seeds` folder to your package `composer.json` autoload
   classmap array.
4. In terminal, run `composer update` from your package root folder.
5. In terminal, run `php artisan db:seed --class={Package}Seeder`
   (replace class name with the new class name.)

That's it. You can now run seeds for your package.

M

Answer (score 2):

To make sure your seed files do not conflict, you can add a namespace to the seed file

```
namespace YourPackage\Name;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder {
```

And then run the artisan command with the FQCN

```
$ php artisan db:seed --class="YourPackage\Name\DatabaseSeeder"
```

or if you are not using the quotation marks

```
$ php artisan db:seed --class=YourPackage\\Name\\DatabaseSeeder
```